# ¿Cómo evaluar si existe un valor en particular en todas las llaves de un diccionario que tiene arreglos como valores en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, array, condiciones, bucles, diccionarios

Digamos que tengo el siguiente diccionario en un programa Python:

```
the_dictionary_list = {
    'Color': ['None', 'Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'], 
    'Cuerpo': ['None', 'Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 
    'Fondo': ['None', 'Oceano.png'], 
    'Ojos': ['None', 'Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'], 
    'Pinzas': ['None', 'Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 
    'Puas': ['None', 'Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']
}
```

Cómo puedo evaluar que el elemento `'None'` existe como valor en  todas las llaves del diccionario de arriba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para verificar si existe 'None' en todos elementos, una forma sencilla (no se si la más eficiente) es con un ciclo y preguntando valor por valor si existe el elemento.

Escrito lo anterior usando [comprensión](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) en [diccionarios](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques):

```
res = all('None' in y for x, y in the_dictionary_list.items())
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Ahora lo entiendo claramente :)

Comment: Puedes evitarte el unpacking recorriendo solo los valores del diccionario con `the_dictionary_list.values()`.